# How to install packages in Tcl?

Tags: linux, package, tcl, package-managers

I am trying to install `critlib` on my machine (http://equi4.com/critlib/), so that I can create zip files dynamically in Tcl.

The issue is that I have no idea how to install Tcl packages. Is there a certain place you put the folders? Is there a command like `yum` I can use?

I've skimmed the various Tcl beginners guides and read the sections about packages, but every source always seems to be assuming knowledge I lack.

Comment: What _exact_ platform are you on? For this question, that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some directories. To list them, execute `tclsh` and enter

```
join $auto_path \n
```

In each of that directory and its subdir (but not the sub-sub-dir) tcl looks for a file called `pkgIndex.tcl`.

So if you got an archive, extract it, look where the `pkgIndex.tcl` is, and copy the directory where this file is in to one of the paths `$auto_path`. The problem is only to select the appropiate path from the output of step 1.

If you are not sure what the appropiate directory is, I suggest editing the output from the first step into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode and made virtual environment then you can do it as follows
"pipenv install tcl"

Comment: This does not answer the original question. OP is not asking how to install `tcl` with `pipenv`.